# Angular Pipe method not updating the data in every click

Tags: angular

I have this pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { orderBy } from 'lodash';

@Pipe({ name: 'sortBy' })
export class SortByPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any[], order = '', column: string = ''): any[] {
    if (!value || order === '' || !order) { return value; } // no array
    if (value.length <= 1) { return value; } // array with only one item
    if (!column || column === '') { 
      if(order==='asc'){return value.sort()}
      else{return value.sort().reverse();}
    } // sort 1d array
    return orderBy(value, [column], [order]);
  }
}
```

Are then this method:

```
order = 'asc'; // Initialized

changeOrder(order) {
    this.order = order; // asc or desc
}
```

Which I change using this:

```
<button (click)="changeOrder('asc')">ASC</button>
<button (click)="changeOrder('desc')">DESC</button>

Order is: {{ order }}

<div *ngFor="let dat of data | sortBy: order">
    {{ dat.name }}
</div>
```

What I click the buttons to change the order the order variable is changed every time but the order is not changed every time unless I click both buttons.

What is this happening ... how can I fix this?

Comment: can you create stackblitz?

Comment: My guess is something to do with change detection. It might be that when you fire the event (click) it changes variable and sorts, but the view is not updated because the array was ordered after change detection. Try this out by adding a second parameter to your pipe, next to name:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'sortBy' , pure: false})
```

If this fixes it, then beware that it might slow down the performance of your app (if you have a long running function on this). Better to search for another solution that will not slow down your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use pure: false at the name of Pipe. Like this:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'sortBy',
  pure: false
})
```

Comment: consider performance issues with impure pipes. check angular documentation.
While an impure pipe can be useful, be careful using one. A long-running impure pipe could dramatically slow down your app.